# CSS3 transformed div moves when browser is resized

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My column looks like this:

[image]

This looks fine but when I shrink the browser the `div` *moves up* like so:

[image]

I want it to stay in place as it shrinks:

[image]

Any idea what's going on here - is there a css fix for this?

js (react):

```
<div>
     <Icon name="plus" style={{display: 'block', margin: '0 auto'}}/>
     <div className="rotate-div">TESTING</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.rotate-div {
    transform: rotate(270deg) !important;
    margin-top: 30px !important;
}
```

I tried increasing height of container, removing padding, adding more margin but nothing seems to make a difference.

Comment: It's better if you can create jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks good idea next time I will. In my answer I used a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

First I wouldn't recommend using `!important` at all, it's bad practice and mixes up your code. here you simply need to make a padding between the "Testing" and the icon. For the rotate div:

```
.rotate-div {

    padding-top: 20px; /* You can change the pixel amount */

}
```

remove the margin-top and !importants

Comment: why is `!important` bad practice? It makes it easier for me to override default css of semantic-ui and other UI packages. What do you suggest I do instead?

Comment: Use good CSS practice. !important clog your code and mix it up. You need to understand how things override other things. If this is a profession you want to go into, I highly recommend dropping the habit

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was easier for me to use `position: relative` on the parent element and `position: absolute` on the child element.

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aqmbbL2s/1/